# How to get (No)LineFinal to work for Hoefler Text Italic with TeX Live 2013?

Tags: fonts, xetex, texlive, mactex

I’ve just installed MacTeX 2013, which includes TeX Live 2013. This somehow breaks the `Contextuals=(No)LineFinal` feature from `fontspec` with Hoefler Text Italic.

It works as I expect with MacTeX 2012 (which I fortunately still have installed).

The following file is typeset with a swash on the final n with MacTeX 2013, but not with MacTeX 2012.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont [UprightFeatures={Contextuals=NoLineFinal}]{Hoefler Text Italic}
% One could use [ItalicFeatures={Contextuals=NoLineFinal}]{Hoefler Text}
% and add a \itshape or \textit to the document

\begin{document}

There should be no swash to this last n

\end{document}
```

Compiling `aat-info.tex` reports the same features with both version of MacTeX, and in both case, it reports Line Final Swashes as *on*.

Is it a new bug or was I unknowingly relying on an old, now fixed, one? In any case, how could I get the swashes to disappear again?

---

I’m still looking into the issue, and this is likely related.

With Apple Chancery, I can’t find a way to turn *on* Line Initial Swashes or Line Final swashes in MacTeX 2013. In MacTeX 2012, `LineInitial` triggers *very* often, including in the middle of a line. It seems to me it does the same thing as `WordInitial`.

In both MacTeX 2012 and 2013, `WordInitial` and `WordFinal` appear to work fine when turned on.

Once again, `aat-info.tex` reports the same features and defaults when run with MacTeX 2012 or 2013. However, MacTeX 2013 reports them in french (my system default) while MacTeX 2012 does it in english.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont {Apple Chancery}
% Explicitly turn on Word initial/final swashes
% \setmainfont [Contextuals={WordInitial, WordFinal}]{Apple Chancery}
% Explicitly turn on Line initial/final swashes - actually the default
% \setmainfont [Contextuals={LineInitial, LineFinal}]{Apple Chancery}
% Explicitly turn off Line initial/final swashes
% \setmainfont [Contextuals={NoLineInitial, NoLineFinal}]{Apple Chancery}

\begin{document}

% Examples courtesy of Apple
Rolling hills, Rolling\\
pines, Rolling thunder

Pears, pinapples, cherries\\
and so many grapes

I saw one in a box once

\end{document}
```

---

Next step, try pure XeTeX. Unfortunately, I don’t know much about it.

Comment: I get `AAT feature 'Contextuals=NoLineFinal' (8,7) not available in font 'Hoefler Text'`

Comment: They are only available for italics, `[ItalicFeatures={Contextuals=NoLineFinal}]{Hoefler Text}` or `[UprightFeatures={Contextuals=NoLineFinal}]{Hoefler Text Italic}`.

Comment: `AAT feature 'Contextuals=NoLineFinal' (8,7) not available in font 'Hoefler Text/I'`; however this might depend on the OS (I'm on 10.8.4). I don't get the swash anyway.

Comment: I’m on 10.6.8. Not really reassuring for future compatibility... Oh, well, I’m trying to get rid of them anyway.

Comment: Actually, if I try it with TL 2012 I get errors. :(

Comment: Try processing `aat-info.tex` (you will need to modify it to use Hoefler Text Italic) and see what font features it reports in both TeX Live versions. I only have 10.8 here and they have “fixed” the font and removed this feature.

Comment: Both report the same features, including 8.6, Line Final Swashes. In any case, I’m trying to _turn off_ the feature. It’s availability is not the issue.

Comment: Oh, by the way, when they “fixed” the font, did they at least replaced the set hyphens and dashes to lowercase by default instead of uppercase?

Comment: If they report the same feature set, then the issue is somewhere else other than the engine (I was worried it might be a bug from the Core Text port). As for the hyphen, I don’t know. I don’t use Mac fonts that much (well, I don’t use them at all, except for the occasional test), so I can’t tell the difference.

Comment: I experience the same behaviour; while it's solved, I found a workaround: try adding `Renderer=ICU` as the first option to `\setmainfont`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with particular versions of a font.

Comment: I must say I disagree. It seems to me the font is working fine, that the issue is with XeTeX in this case, and could very well appear with other fonts (as it does for Apple Chancery). I’ve filled a bug report which seemingly did not get much attention. Now, I must admit the question could be edited to be clearer. I’ll get to it.